# Execute function after Google Maps API is loaded

Tags: jquery, function, google-maps

I have the following script which basically loads the Google Maps API. This comes from their documentation.

```
function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Now my problem is that I have a seperate function called GetMap() which basically uses the API to generate a Google Map, but, this function keeps firing before the API has loaded and as a result the map only loads if I for example have a button to load it, or if I do an alert. How can I get around this? I've tried deferring the main script file. I've tried adding the above to document.ready with the function in document.load and vica versa. None of these worked.

Comment: @Lloyd Hi, no, not quite what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already included the `callback` parameter on the URL, all you need to do is include the function:

```
function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function initialize() {
    alert("Map loaded, do some other stuff...");
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: Hi there, this didn't quite do the trick. However adding my getMap function as the callback worked. Thanks, will mark as answer.